# Why is "free" saying this that my pointer is invalid?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
while(n >= 0);
    node * point = malloc(sizeof(node));
    point = create(number, n);

    //show(point);

    //free memory
    while(point != NULL)
    {
        node *tmp = point->next;
        free(point);
        point = tmp;
    }

}

node * create(int data[], int len)
{
    node * list_head;
    node * list;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            list_head = malloc(sizeof(node));
            list = malloc(sizeof(node));
            list_head->value = data[0];
            list_head->next = list;
        }
        else
        {
            list->value = data[i];
            list->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
            list->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return list_head;
}
```

This code is returning an error which is:- free(): invalid pointer
Aborted | Why is my code not freeing the memory that I allocated. Is it because I have allocated that in some different function?

Comment: Fyi, C pointers are not Java or C# references. This code leaks memory like mad.

Comment: `while(n >= 0);` looks like infinite loop or no-op

Comment: Having these two lines `list->next = malloc(sizeof(node));   list->next = NULL;` indicates an error

Comment: Apart from the other mistakes, when you allocate `list`, you don't initialize it. So the final ->next is always indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should be changed to:

```
while(n >= 0) {
    node * point = create(number, n);
```

and:

```
list->next = NULL;
```

should be changed to

```
list = list->next;
```